# Porting nested for loops with non unitary increments in indexing to CUDA kernels

Tags: arrays, loops, cuda, indexing, nested

EDIT: Edited in solution and wrote some code to help people trying to implement nested for loops.

So I am tying to implement the following nested for loop in a cuda kernel:

```
for (unsigned in=1;in<=N;in++){         
     for (unsigned ie=1;ie<=N-1;ie+=2){
         // do some stuff with x[in and/or ie] and z[in and/or ie]
}
```

where x and z are simple 1D arrays copied from the host.

Now, in terms of the nested for loop implementation, this should be relatively straight forward as far as I am aware (as seen with the idx and idy indexing below, can someone confirm this please?). My other question is though, how can I increment ie by 2, without using any sort of if statements and % in my kernel which I expect to affect performance?

```
__global__ void myKernel(double x, double z, int N){

    // define indecies for storing counters
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

    // define counters
    int in = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + (threadIdx.x + 1); // 1-based indexing
    int ie = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + (threadIdx.y)) * 2 + 1;

    z[i*N+j] = ie; // stores odd indicies [ie]

    // do some stuff with (in-ie), x[ie and/or in], z[ie and/or in]...
}

int main(){
    int N = 5; //arbitrary size of arrays
    int threadsPerBlock = 8; // semi-arbitrary, max 512 but depends on GPU device
    dim3 block(threadsPerBlock, threadsPerBlock/2 + 1); // launch N/2 + 1 threads in the second dimension since we are only interested in odd numbered indices.
    dim3 grid( (N-1+threadsPerBlock)/threadsPerBlock, (N-1+threadsPerBlock)/threadsPerBlock);

    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> z;
    z.resize(N*N);
    x.resize(N);

    //copy to device(d_x, d_z);

    //call the kernel
    myKernel<<<grid, block>>>(d_x, d_z, N);

    // retrieve from device

    return 0;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
int ie = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + (threadIdx.y + 1);
```

you make this 2n + 1:

```
int ie = (blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y) * 2 + 1;
```

And you obviously only need N x N/2 threads.

Comment: But then my kernels are executing with ie = 2, 4, 6, 8. Which means I should start them at 0, then multiply by 2 and add 1 after!

Comment: Sorry - I missed the fact that you are using 1-based indexing - fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Paul, it's funny sometimes how a solution so simple can be overlooked :/

Comment: How much does it matter if I'm launching more kernels than I need? Does the number of kernels currently executing affect the performance?

Comment: @Armen: you should only launch as many *blocks* as you actually need. Also if N does not factorise conveniently then you'll also need to check that your `ie`, `in` index values are not out of bounds,

Comment: @ArmenSafieh-Garabedian: u can do a very simple test for that.. considering u always have the bounds checked u can try launching more number of threads(say 2 or 3 times more) than the expected and check the performance..